# Convert ActiveXObject returnvalue to JQuery-Object to process XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, activexobject

I work on a webproject and need to read a xml file. The project was using a webserver and shall now run local on Internet Explorer without the use of a webserver.

I already managed to read an xml-file locally but i need to change my processing of the input, because I cant use .ajax() anymore.

My old Code was:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "myXML.xml",
  async: false,
  success: function(XMLMediaArray) {
    $(XMLmediaArray).find('element[...]').each(function(index, element) {
      var $myMedia = $(this);
      $myMedia.children().each(function(index, element) {
        var $media = $(this);
        //.....//
      });
    });
  }
})
```

My new code for local access is:

```js
try {
  xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlDoc.async = "false";
  xmlDoc.load("myXML.xml");
  
  //How to process with find() ?
  
} catch (ex) {
  alert("exception:" + ex);
}
```

How can i convert the return value from xmlDoc.xml to a jquery-object that can be processed as in the old code.
I need to be able to do something like:

```
$(xmlDoc.xml).find('page[name="' + service.pageName + '"]').each(function (index, element) { // ....//
```

Thanks for any idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object.

```
$xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var obj = {
        name: $xml.find('name').text(),
        age: $xml.find('age').text(),
        gender: $xml.find('gender').text()
    };
```